# What could be CSS causes of breaking under footer

Tags: css

As you see in the image, under the footer there is white part which is not body.

I checked that all the div is closed> I am using html5. I am wondering if anyone can suggest possible causes of this problem.

Thanks in advance.

[image: white part under the footer]

Comment: Going to need to see some markup and existing css.

Comment: like @kinakuta said, we need the code hehe. Check the size of the inner elements.

Comment: Without doubt, your site got hacked and hidden base64 spam code has been inserted. Destroy everything. EVERYTHING

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the `html`'s height to 100%.

Answer (score 0):

I once faced the same exact problem. I got it solved by removing a css file that wasn't required by the site and it was messing up the with default rules.